# Custom lock screen with text overlay

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, lockscreen

I'd like to enable lock screen support in my app: a custom background image with a custom text overlay.

I've looked all over the net (including Stackoverflow) and have not come across any resource that walks you through *both* needs. The ones I've encountered simply show you how to setup a custom background image with no tips on how to add a custom text overlay on top of it (for reference, I want to add a 4-6 column Grid over the image - this is for a weather app).

For example, http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Dynamic_Lock_Screen_for_Windows_Phone_8 is probably the best tutorial I've found on the subject and it actually touches on the concept I'm after, but it doesn't show you actually how to achieve the intended effect, rather it just states that it's possible.

Any guidance here would be much appreciated, either through sample code or relevant links.

Many thanks,

Bardi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you have managed to set a custom image as the lock screen image. The only thing you need now is to create your own image. You can do it using `WritableBitmap` (if you're using Silverlight), or `RenderTargetBitmap` (in case of Windows Runtime).

Here are links that will help you:

- [Converting XAML into an image in Windows Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511564)
- [Windows Store 8.1: Save visual element to bitmap image file](http://basquang.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/windows-store-8-1-save-visual-element-to-bitmap-image-file/)